# Qgis nightly build - DEM error

Tags: qgis, dem

I installed Qgis 1.8 several months ago.  It's been working like a charm.  Earlier today, I decided to check out the latest nightly build.  Installed GDAL 1.10 (already had 1.9 installed) and SQLite 3.7.16 first, then the nightly build.  It's been running fine, however, I just tried to to some DEM raster analysis...which does not work at all.  I get an error message - "An error has occured while executing Python code".  Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS nightly (master), is not stable.
At the moment not least due to [some recent changes in the python API](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Python_plugin_API_changes_from_18_to_20) which requires a lot of updates to python code what has not yet been completed.

For any such problems, please:

- Fix them and submit a pull request (if you are able to)
- Hire a professional developer to fix this (if you are able to)
- [File a bug](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) with as much information concerning the error as possible and instructions on how to reproduce